# Defining xml layout by device's resolution

Tags: android, android-layout

I was given a task to provide devices with < 1024x800 resolution with one group of layouts and >=1024x800 - with another.

Below there's some code I'm using. Regarding on _isTablet flag application can decide which layout it should use.

Do you think it's a decent tactic or should I consider another functionality for achieving ***resolution-based*** segregation of design layouts ? Thanks.

```
Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
    final int height = display.getHeight();
    final int width = display.getWidth();

    _leadingSideResolution = Math.max(height, width);
    if (_leadingSideResolution <= HANDSET_LAYOUT_RESOLUTION) {
            _isTablet = false;
    } else if(_leadingSideResolution > HANDSET_LAYOUT_RESOLUTION 
                && _leadingSideResolution <= TABLET_LAYOUT_RESOLUTION) {
            _isTablet = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code to check whether the device is tablet or not

```
  public  boolean onTablet()
   {
     int intScreenSize = context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout &   Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK;

     return (intScreenSize == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE) // LARGE
     || (intScreenSize == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE + 1); // Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE
    }  



    if(!onTablet())
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.not_tablet_layout);
    }
     else
    {
       setContentView(R.layout.tablet_layout); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For supporting android mobile devices and tablets, android has provided a very simple solution. You can get it from: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

From this please read:

```
 1. How to Support Multiple Screen
 2. Designing alternative layouts and drawables
 3. Declaring Tablet Layouts for Android 3.2
 4. Configuration examples
```

Comment: I'm sorry but - Have you read my question ? There's nothing there that makes clear how to distinguish between layouts by resolution value.